# What is the most efficient way to populate one pandas dataframe using another dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

I am wondering how I can most efficiently do the following operation so that I can also upscale it to dataframes with million rows+.
I have 2 panda dataframes:

Data1:

```
Position    Letter
1           a
2           b
3           c
4           b
5           a
```

Data2:

```
Weight    Letter
1           a
2           b
3           c
```

Now I want to create an extra column(weight) in data 1 resulting in the following:

```
Position    Letter   Weight
1           a          1
2           b          2
3           c          3
4           b          2
5           a          1
```

Answer (score 1):

Best way is to use merge:

```
df = df1.merge(df2, on=['Letter'])
print(df)

   Position Letter  Weight
0         1      a       1
1         5      a       1
2         2      b       2
3         4      b       2
4         3      c       3
```